# laravel approving and disapproving a request by user as an admin

Tags: laravel-5

am developing an application where the user sends an application to admin who either approves or disapproves... the field am using to store this data have a boolean value 0 for accepted 1 for rejected,,, n  bytheway am new in laravel so this may be a wrong approach... do anyone have a way of using a button to change the values in the database from 0 to 1 when accepted and 1 to zero when rejected... av been searching for this and can't find a good approach to do this... kindly assist﻿

here is my  application model

```html
//relates application_id and admin_id

public function approveApplications()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Martin\Models\Application','applications','application_id','admin_id');
}


public function approved() // returns all applications that are approved
{
  return $this->approveApplications()->wherePivot('approved',true)->get();
}
```

and my admin model

```html
 public function application()
 {
  return $this->hasMany('Martin\Models\Application');
 }
```

**I have this for my migrations**

```html
  Schema::create('applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
          $table->integer('admin_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
          $table->integer('application_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
          $table->string('acronym');
          $table->string('destination');
          $table->integer('Number_of_days_hired');
          $table->string('vehicle_registration_number');
          $table->timestamp('departure_date_and_time');
          $table->boolean('approved')->default(0);
          $table->timestamp("created_at")->useCurrent();
          $table->timestamp("updated_at")->useCurrent();
          $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
          $table->foreign('admin_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('admins')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
          });
    }
```

I want to achieve this in the application

[image: approving and disapproving]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating the issue too much :)
The best approach is to add two seperate routes to your routes file:

```
Route::post('application/approve/{id}', 'YourController@postApprove');
Route::post('application/reject/{id}', 'YourController@postReject');
```

Now you will link your Approve and Reject buttons to the routes above and you need to make sure form buttons will link to those two routes and send an ID of the Application you want to approve/reject.
In your controller you will do the modification of the Application 'approved' field -> for example:

```
public function postApprove($id) {
    $application = Application::where('id', '=', e($id))->first();
    if($application)
    {
        $application->approved = 1;
        $application->save();
        //return a view or whatever you want tto do after
    }
}
```

Do the similar for reject method, except you will set "approved" field to false or 0.

Comment: am glad you replied @Vojko am just wondering why use post routes instead of get routes.. then why use the e($id) instead of id... I know this may not very good to ask and my apologies... am actually using this approach but av changed the boolean to integer so that the when the user offer is rejected it stores as 2 instead of one... is this a gud approach... again thanks for replying...

Comment: Using post since user is posting the data to server, not getting it from server. For this specific problem, you might also use Get... But beware that Get method is easier to tamper with and one might guess the link without ever going to your website (Read more about forgery requests by googleing CSRF). e($id) is used to escape the characters if, for example someone tampers with the data sent to server, to prevent harmful data. It is data sanitizing. As for integer, use whatever suits you as long as you don't get lost on what you are using. I would prefer true/false combination.

Comment: If the answer helped you and you solved your problem, mark as answer please :)

Comment: Hello @Vojko still working on it but when I click the buttons they give method not allowed error also is this the right way to write the routes in the buttons `{{route('approvedApplications',['id'=>$application->id])}}`

Comment: when i use get it gives this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()` ... when i remove the save() method it gives a flash message that the application was approved but in the database nothing happens what should I do? I will be grateful on your reply...  `    _public function postApprove($id)
{   $application=Application::where('id','=',$id);
   if($application){
     $application->approved=1;
     return redirect()->back()->with('info','The application was approved successfully');
   }}_ ' save for postReject.Thanks

Comment: $application=Application::where('id','=',$id)->first();

Comment: Try that instead of the $application=Application::where('id','=',$id);

Comment: As for the button, you should create a post form that includes the button in it. Form action should point to your post route.

Comment: one for approve button, one for reject button

Comment: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:` error message using the post method

Comment: hello @ Vojko,,, am now able to change the value from 0 to 1 and vice varsa using you method above I used update instead of the above thanks for your support so far.... its a great honour from you... one last thing from here... how do I keep track of the disapproved applications... av used the update function as follows : `
     $application=Application::where('id','=',$id)->update(['approved'=>1]);
     return redirect()->back()->with('info','The application was approved successfully');
   }`

Comment: To keep track of disapproved ones, i would suggest that you use three values so 0 would be pending, 1 would be approved and 2 would be rejected

Comment: perfect... it was so smooth